# Proving a binomial sum identity $\sum _{k=0}^n \binom nk \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

*Mathematica* tells me that

$$\sum _{k=0}^n { n \choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}.$$

Although I have not been able to come up with a proof.

Proofs, hints, or references are all welcome.

Comment: The method at this [MSE link I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912720/) and this [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254416/) applies here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could consider the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx .$$

Comment: Aha this is the integral I was searching for! Using the integral $\int_0^1 (1-t)^n \, dt$ I was able to prove $\sum _{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ I thought there should be a corresponding integral to my problem and after seeing your answer the integral I was searching for is obvious now!

Comment: @yjj Then have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals

Answer (score 7):

Sums of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}f(k)$$
can often be attacked via the 
[Calculus of finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

Comment: This is also a [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform).

Comment: How would you continue with finite differences in this problem?

Answer (score 7):

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}$$

We have:

$$\begin{align}S_n&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{n}{n-k}.\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{n(2n+1)}{n-k}.\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{2n^2-2nk+2nk+n}{n-k}.\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{2n^2-2nk}{n-k}.\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}\right]\\&+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\dfrac{2nk+n}{n-k}.\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}+\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{n-k}\\
&=\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\right]+\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}}{(2k+1)}+\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left[(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\right]\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$S_n=\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}S_{n-1}+0
\Rightarrow S_{n-1}=\dfrac{2n-2}{2n-1}S_{n-2}
...
\Rightarrow S_1=\dfrac{2}{3}S_0$$
and $S_0=1$

Hence,
$$S_n=\dfrac{2n(2n-2)...2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)...3.1}=\dfrac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

Comment: As stated, you divide by zero since you sum to $k=n$ and $n-k$ is in the denominator.

Comment: Wah! Thanks for pointing out errors in my solution.

Comment: Fix this problem as follows sum for $k=0$ to $n-1$ and $k=n$ is calculated separately

Comment: You can edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your identity is a special case of the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chu-VandermondeIdentity.html).

${}_2 F_1(-n,b;c;1)=\frac{(c-b)_n}{(c)_n}$

with $b=\frac12$ and $c=\frac32$. More info on it is in A=B, as mentioned already by John.

Comment: It's on page 181.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{ n \choose k}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2k + 1} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{ n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2k}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{ n \choose k}\pars{-x^{2}}^{k}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x^{2}}^{n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{n}x^{-1/2}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\,{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 3/2}}
\\[5mm] &=
{n!\pars{1/2}! \over \pars{n + 1/2}!}\qquad\qquad\qquad
\pars{~\mbox{Note that}\ {1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 2} = \Gamma\pars{3 \over 2} = \pars{1 \over 2}!~}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{1 \over \ds{n + 1/2 \choose n}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer specific help, but I'd recommend thumbing through [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025) looking for techniques.  It has many sums that look similar, though of course the difficulty is in the details.

There's also the book [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html), but Concrete Mathematics gives an introduction to the content of A=B and in my opinion is easier to read, so I'd start with Concrete Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

There are a powerful **algorithms generalizing telescopy** (Gosper, Zeilberger et al.) that easily tackle this case of the **Chu-Vandermonde identity** and much more complicated sums. For example, see [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.71.3348) which gives as an application a very interesting q-analogy - namely that L. J. Rogers' classical finite version of **Euler's pentagonal number theorem** is simply the dual of a special case of a q-Chu-Vandermonde.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to prove

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} {n\choose k}
= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

we introduce

$$f(z) = n! (-1)^n \frac{1}{2z+1} \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

This has the property that for $0\le k\le n$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z)
= n! (-1)^n \frac{1}{2k+1}
\prod_{q=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q}
\prod_{q=k+1}^n \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^n \frac{1}{2k+1}
\frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
= \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} {n\choose k}.$$

Note that the residue of $f(z)$ at infinity is zero by inspection and
residues sum to zero so that we have

$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z)
= - \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1/2} f(z)
\\ = - \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Res}_{z=-1/2} \; n! (-1)^n
\frac{1}{z+1/2} \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
= - \frac{1}{2} n! (-1)^n
\prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{-1/2-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} n! \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{1/2+q}
= 2^n n! \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{2q+1}
= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}.$$

This is the claim.