# Why is $\pi$ so close to $3$?

Tags: pi

$\pi\approx 3.141592654$

Why is it so close to $3$?

I find this intriguing, this cannot be a coincidence.

Comment: Would you prefer it farther away?

Comment: Because a regular hexagon is "so close to" a circle?

Comment: Put the unit circle between two regular $n$-gons, one circumscribed by the circle, and the other inscribing the circle, for $n \ge 12$. The area of the outer polygon tells how close $\pi$ is to 3.

Comment: I was trying to find who it was that took the fact that _both_ $ \ \pi \ $ and $ \ e \ $ are close to 3 as a sign of the Trinity. I find it more interesting that _those_ numbers are close together.  (But there are many interesting irrational -- even transcendental -- numbers, and it is reasonable that humans would locate  smaller ones first.)

Comment: And why is the golden ratio $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.62$?  The answer?  Because that's what it is.

Comment: I should also comment that some consider $\pi$ to be the wrong value.  Why not define $\pi$ as the ratio of the circumference to the radius?  Then, instead of $C = 2\pi r$, we would have $C = \pi r$.  People tend to use the radius more often than the diameter.  Furthermore, then there would be $\pi$ "radians" in a full circle (why should it be $2\pi$, why multiply by $2$)?  Then you'd be asking why is $\pi$ so close to $6$?  And the answer would be the same, because it is.

Comment: Why is $e$ so close to ${ 2718281828 \over 1000000000} $? An accident perhaps?

Comment: @copper.hat This cannot be a coincidence either. :-)

Comment: What do you mean close? It's also close to 0 and 100.

Comment: @Did: Its déjà vu all over again.

Comment: Because the following integral is small

$$\pi-3=2\int_0^1\frac{x(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: and the following series as well
$$\pi-3=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{(1+k)(1+2k)(1+4k)}$$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you can clearly see from this figure, $2\pi\simeq6\iff\pi\simeq3$, since the side of the inscribed regular polygon is equal to the radius of the circle:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image: 1]

Answer (score 8):

Let $a<b$ be integers.  Pick a number, which we'll call $\pi'$ in $[a,b]$ uniformly at random.  The chance that $\pi'$ is within $\pi-3\approx .1415$ of some integer is $2(\pi-3)\approx .283$.

If something has a near $30\%$ chance of occuring at random, I would say that it could definitely just be a coincidence.