# Prove that $\pi>3$ using geometry

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I was asked this question today in an interview.

**Question**: Prove that $\pi>3$ using geometry.

They gave me hints about drawing a unit circle and then inscribing an equilateral triangle and then proceeding. But I could not follow. Can anyone help?

Comment: How is pi defined?

Comment: @miracle173 How does that help?

Comment: How do you want to show something about pi if you have not definition of it?

Comment: Inscribe a regular hexagon!

Comment: @miracle173 of course there is the conventional definition.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Haven't tried that but know that works.Can you proceed with the triangle?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Think about the perimeter of the hexagon.

Comment: An equilateral triangle inscribed in a unit circle has perimeter $3\sqrt{3}$, which is not of itself obviously helpful. Offhand I'd guess the interviewer was trying to guide you toward the idea of inscribing a suitable polygon, in this case a regular hexagon.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729907) question.

Comment: A much more related question: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111434/prove-that-%cf%80-3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inscribed hexagon in the unit circle has perimeter $6$. The perimeter of the circle is $2\pi$, hence $\pi > 3$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $>$ and not $ \ge $?

Comment: http://imgur.com/IbOElsj

Comment: Arguably this involves six equilateral triangles

Comment: How do you prove that the perimeter of the hexagon is smaller than the perimeter of the circle (really "prove", not say "it is clear that...")?

Answer (score 5):

The inscribed $12$-gon in the unit circle has area $\frac{12}{2}\sin (2\pi/12)=3$. The area of the unit circle is $\pi$. Hence $\pi\ge 3$.

Comment: Thanks, But can you use the triangle and do so?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $>$ and not $ \ge $?

Comment: I like this argument based on area than another one on this thread based on perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is redundant, but:

If an equilateral triangle is inscribed in a unit circle, and if, on each side of the inscribed triangle, an isosceles triangle is further inscribed in the circle, then an equilateral hexagon with each side of length $=1$ results; but then $6 < 2\pi$ implies $3 < \pi$.

So is this something you are after?

Comment: Not really.. I just want the proof using a triangle.. without constructing a hexagon.

Comment: @Aniket I would say the hint just provides a starting point; by inscribing suitable triangles twice we arrives at something useful, is not it? :)

Comment: In that case.. I mean if you look at it in that way... It is fine.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of cheating, you don't need the whole hexagon...

Let $O$ be the centre of the unit circle with equilateral $\triangle ABC$ inscribed in it.  Extend $\vec {AO}$ to meet the circle at D.

As $BC$ and $OD$ are perpendicular bisectors of each other,  $\triangle OBD$ is isosceles, and hence $|BD|=1$.  But this must be smaller than the minor arc subtended, which has length $\dfrac{\pi}3$.

Comment: Could the downvoter comment why?