# Can someone give an analytical proof that $\pi$ is greater than 3?

Tags: calculus, inequality, pi

The geometrical proof is simple, but I want to know how to prove $\pi \gt 3$ by using basic calculus?

Comment: How do you have $\pi$ defined?  If you have it defined as or can use the result $\pi = 4(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{11}+\dots)$ you will see after the seventh term the partial sums will remain above $3$

Comment: $\sin(y) < y$ for $y>0$, let $y=\pi /6$

Comment: Note the following post, using geometry: [Prove that $\pi > 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540947/prove-that-pi3-using-geometry)

Comment: @amWhy Not a duplicate of any of the linked questions. Also, this question got some good and interesting answers, much better than the linked questions. Please consider to reopen.

Answer (score 6):

$$\sin(x)<x$$
whenever $x>0$. Take $x=\pi/6$.

ADDED IN EDIT

Apologies to Spine Feast who just pipped me to this, but
$$\frac\pi6=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}>\int_0^{1/2}dt=\frac12$$
is the same thing again but even more analytical.

Answer (score 6):

The integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x(1-x)^2}{1+x^2}dx$$

evaluates to $\frac{\pi-3}{2}$ and the result is positive because the integrand is $\ge0$ in the interval $(0,1)$.

A related series is 
$$\pi = 3+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{24}{(4k+2)(4k+3)(4k+5)(4k+6)}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature column in AMS titled [Calculating Pi using Elementary Calculus](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-pi-calc) that you might want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many, but here is a proof that uses the famous infinite sum

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$  Solving for $\pi$ and using the fact that an infinite sum of positive terms increases monotonically to its limit, we see that

$$
\pi = \left(6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} > \left(6\sum_{n=1}^7\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}> \sqrt{9} = 3
$$  You can see that $6\sum_{n=1}^7 \frac{1}{n^2} > 9$ by direct calculation.

Comment: A similar one that proves $\pi^2>9$ directly is
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3}{((k+1)(k+2))^2}=\pi^2-9$$