# How to prove this $\pi$ formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, pi

I am hoping to find out where the formula 
$$\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{\left(2k+1\right)!!}$$
comes from. I can't see how one could begin to prove it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/14116/42969

Comment: If you are wondering on the untimely fast response, it is because I had derived this formula just last month!  :D  AH!  I am so happy to write this answer.

Comment: And I am so happy to find people like you here :) I wish anything I paid for was delivered in an 'untimely fast' manner. Passion is such an awesome motivator.

Comment: @J.A.K. Haha, I work for free man, no tipping allowed.  But if you wanted to, you could drop by in [my chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art), where I hang out often.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{\left(2k+1\right)!!}x^k=\frac{2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{(2-x) x}}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici do you know how to prove this nice identity in a elementary fashion? i only can do it invovling the error function

Comment: @tired Lol, probably cheating, but you can brute force apply Taylor's theorem to the RHS.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. You are totally correct ! I found the result (from a CAS) really nice. Cheers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let us start with the geometric series:

$$\frac1{1-r}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k$$

If we let $r=-x^2$ and integrate both sides from zero to one, we get the famous [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for $\pi$.

$$\frac\pi4=\arctan(1)=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-x^2)^k\ dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

Applying an [Euler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation), we arrive at

$$\begin{align}\frac\pi4&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{1+n}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\text{simplifying the inner sum}\\\\&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{k!}{(2k+1)!!}\end{align}$$

The simplifying step comes by noting that

$$\sum_{k=0}^0\binom0k\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac11=2^0\frac{0!}{1!!}\color{green}\checkmark$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^1\binom1k\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\left(\frac11-\frac13\right)=2^1\frac{1!}{3!!}\color{green}\checkmark$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^2\binom2k\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\left(\frac11-\frac13\right)-\left(\frac13-\frac15\right)=2^2\frac{2!}{5!!}\color{green}\checkmark$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^3\binom3k\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\left[\left(\frac11-\frac13\right)-\left(\frac13-\frac15\right)\right]-\left[\left(\frac13-\frac15\right)-\left(\frac15-\frac17\right)\right]=2^3\frac{3!}{7!!}\color{green}\checkmark$$

You can prove by induction (and some observation) that the denominators are clearly odd double factorials, and with some work, you can derive the numerators.

Comment: Yes, this is one of my favourite posts as well. $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 26):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> [It's well known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) that
> $\ds{\pars{2k + 1}!! = {\pars{2k + 2}! \over 2^{k + 1}\pars{k + 1}!}}$ such that

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k! \over \pars{2k + 1}!!} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k!\pars{k + 1}! \over \pars{2k + 2}!}\,2^{k + 1} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{k + 2} \over
\Gamma\pars{2k + 3}}\,2^{k + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}2^{k + 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}\pars{1 - x}^{k + 1}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{2x\pars{1 - x}}^{\,k}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}{1 \over 1 - 2x\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x \over x^{2} - x + 1/2}\,\dd x =
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}{1/2 - x \over x^{2} + 1/4}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1} = 2\arctan\pars{1} = 2\,{\pi \over 4} = \bbx{\ds{\pi \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful!  +1  I was wondering how to start with the series and snake my way back to the $\pi$, but failed to see the beautiful Beta function.  Might want to reference that part for the viewers.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks. Beta is always a nice 'killer'.

Comment: Lol, I'm still looking at it in awe, as those factorials indeed worked out perfectly.