# Sum of series (quotient of factorials)

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does somebody know how to sum this series

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{(2k+1)!!} $$

This problem is from an article of Joseph Blitzstein where he stopped here. The problem asks to find the probability of having 2 black balls and 1 red. Take randomly one, if you take the black it ends, otherwise you put it back and add another black and another red. It is asked to know the expectancy of the random variable

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to proof it to be the Euler-Mascheroni constant but it is a bit shorter than that.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: The posting's use of *double factorial* is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149340/how-to-prove-this-pi-formula?noredirect=1