# Deriving Maclaurin series for $\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Intrigued by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420732/trying-to-prove-that-sum-j-2-infty-prod-k-1j-frac2-kjk-1-pi/420886#420886) brilliant answer from Ron Gordon, I was attempting to find the Maclaurin series for 
$$f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=g(x)G(x)$$

with $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $G(x)$ its primitive. So I attempted to multipy series, which yielded this:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1} (-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1} { -\frac{1}{2}\choose n-k}{ -\frac{1}{2}\choose k},$$

which I'm unable to simplify further. How to proceed? Or is this approach doomed?

Comment: Maybe try expanding $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ via the binomial theorem, and then dividing.

Comment: Since $f(x)=\frac12(\arcsin^2x)'$, perhaps you should try express this new function in Taylor-Maclaurin series, and then derive it with regard to *x*.

Comment: @Bitrex No. not really it is too symbolic!

Comment: @Lucian Thanks, I am going to try this and work on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1-x^2+x^2t^2}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)=\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
so we can write
$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1(1-t^2)^n\,dt\right)x^{2n+1}.$$
But
$$\int_0^1(1-t^2)^n\,dt=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}t^{2k}\,dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}.$$
Hence,
$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}.$$
Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/proving-a-binomial-sum-identity/247057#247057) for proof of $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1}=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$.

Comment: Hey, can you explain the transition from the first line to the second ? I really looked hard at this, yet frustratingly enough I can't see how you did that.

$ \frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1(1-t^2)^n\,dt\right)x^{2n+1}. $

Where does the integral appear from and how does it relate to the previous one ?

Comment: @Victor Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-t^2)^nx^{2n}$ is a geometric series, so in fact,$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-t^2)^nx^{2n}=\frac1{1-(1-t^2)x^2}=\frac1{1-x^2+x^2t^2}$$
Now, take a look once again!

Comment: That is so slick ! I know this might be really simple for you, but how did you come up with this? I basically mean the first integral and the geometric series part.

Comment: @Victor Oh no, I think the problem is that you like to see from the left to right, while you can also see from the right to left!

Comment: In fact, you want to find the Maclaurin series for $\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, among the all things you may know about this function, one thing can be the following equality
$$\frac{\arcsin(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
So if you try to find an integral representation for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$, this can be useful and really useful when the integrand has also a geometric series representation!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and detailed explanation ! ^_^

Comment: @Victor You're welcome!

Comment: $\int_0^1(1-t^2)^n dt= \int_0^1(1-u)^n u^{-1/2} /2 \, du=\beta(n+1,1/2)/2$

Comment: We can also obtain the formula for $\int_0^1(1-t^2)^n$ by integration by parts: [$\displaystyle\int_0^1(1-x^2)^ndx=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\int_0^1(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1503568).

Answer (score 3):

Another but similar proof which does not need to use the summation formula above is this one. Start with defining

$$I(t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan{\frac{x\sin{t}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$

Then by the Fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-I(0)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x\cos t}{1-x^2\cos^2 t }\mathrm{d}t$$

Ergo

$$\frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\! t\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Denote $J_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\! t\,\mathrm{d}t$, by per partes we have

$$J_n = \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n+1}\! t\,\mathrm{d}t = 2n\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2n-1}\sin^2 t\!\,\mathrm{d}t=2n\left(J_{n-1}-J_{n}\right)$$

So $$J_n = \frac{2n}{2n+1}J_{n-1} =\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}J_{n-2}=\dots = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}J_0=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

since $J_0 = \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\! t\,\mathrm{d}t =1$. Over all we get desired result

$$\frac{\arcsin{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}x^{2n+1}$$

Note: Similar integral would have been also...

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-x\sin t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another proof is using that $f(x)={{\arcsin x}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$ satisfies $(1-x^2)f'=xf+1$, which can be easily verified.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}=\frac12\bigl[(\arcsin x)^2\bigr]'.
\end{equation*}
Accordingly, it is sufficient to find out the power series expansion of $(\arcsin x)^2$ around $x=0$. The fact is
\begin{equation*}
(\arcsin x)^2=2!\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [(2n)!!]^2 \frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}, \quad |x|<1.
\end{equation*}
A more general conclusion than the above power series expansion is
\begin{equation}\label{arcsin-series-expansion-unify}
\biggl(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\biggr)^{k}
=1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\frac{Q(k,2m)}{\binom{k+2m}{k}}\frac{(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{Q(m-k)-sum-dfn}
Q(k,m)=\sum_{\ell=0}^{m} \binom{k+\ell-1}{k-1} s(k+m-1,k+\ell-1)\biggl(\frac{k+m-2}{2}\biggr)^{\ell}
\end{equation}
for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\ge2$.

References

1. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
3. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Series expansions of powers of arcsine, closed forms for special values of Bell polynomials, and series representations of generalized logsine functions*, AIMS Mathematics **6** (2021), no. 7, 7494--7517; available online at https://doi.org/10.3934/math.2021438.
4. F. Qi, *Explicit formulas for partial Bell polynomials, Maclaurin's series expansions of real powers of inverse (hyperbolic) cosine and sine, and series representations of powers of Pi*, Research Square (2021), available online at https://doi.org/10.21203/rs.3.rs-959177/v3.
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661247.
6. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657809.
7. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379986.