# Evaluating:$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients

How to evaluate:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}$$
$\binom{n}{r}$ is the binomial coefficient.

If possible, present different methods as well.

Comment: Duplicate: [Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548563/calculate-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac12k-choose-k)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint.** One may observe that, by integrating by parts (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503530/prove-n-choose-0-frac13n-choose-1-frac15n-choose-2-1n-f/1503568#1503568)), one has
$$
\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{(2n+1)}{2^{2n}}\int_0^1(1-x^2)^ndx
$$ giving
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}=4\int_0^1\frac{\left(5-x^2\right)}{\left(x^2+3\right)^2}dx
$$ then the integral may classically be evaluated by [partial fraction  decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Basic_principles) giving

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac43+\frac{2\pi}{27}\sqrt{3}.
> $$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** In general, $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{\displaystyle{2n\choose n}n^2} ~=~ 2\arcsin^2x.~$ By twice differentiating-and-then- multiplying with regard to *x*, we arrive at the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{70}+\frac{1}{252}+\cdots=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}.$$
A proof of this can be found at [Sprugnoli](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf).

Comment: also try http://oeis.org/A073016