# Limit of a particular infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

How would one calculate the  value of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2},
$$
which by the ratio test is easily seen to be convergent? Is there a general strategy for calculating infinite series, other than mathematical maturity?

Comment: *"which by the ratio test is easily seen to be convergent?"* When I applied it, I got the conclusion that the series diverges.

Comment: My bad you're absolutely right!

Comment: $\binom{2k}{k}$ does not tend to zero as $k\to +\infty$, hence the given series is blatantly divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ the sequence define by
$$
a_n=\frac{\left(2k\right)!}{\left(k!\right)^2}
$$
It is stricly positive and
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(2k+2\right)\left(2k+1\right)\left(2k\right)!}{\left(k+1\right)^2\left(k!\right)^2}\frac{\left(k!\right)^2}{\left(2k\right)!}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}4>1
$$
The series easily diverges. However, with $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}=\frac{2}{27}\left(18+\sqrt{3}\pi\right)
$$

- EDIT WITH OP COMMENT :

This kind of sum is not that easy to calculate. The following proof is really interesting and I suggest you try to prove what I will admit.
In fact, you can write that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{\left(2n\right)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}}
$$
If you study the function $f$ defined on $\left]-1,1\right[$ by
$$
f\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{arcsin}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
You can find a simple differential equation verified by $f$, but you can also search for power series that are also solution of this. By unicity of power series development you will deduce for $x \in \left]-1,1\right[$
$$
f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\displaystyle n\binom{2n}{n}}x^{2n-1}
$$
Then, you can deduce the development on $\left]-1,1\right[$ of 
$$
g\left(x\right)=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}+\frac{x\text{arcsin}\left(x\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
which is
$$
g\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(2n-1\right)}{\displaystyle \left(n+1\right)}\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\displaystyle \binom{2n+2}{n+1}}x^{2n}
$$
For $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{2}$,
$$
g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{4}{3}+\frac{\pi}{12}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{3/2}=\frac{2}{27}\left(18+\sqrt{3}\pi\right)
$$

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you got the sum on your interesting example?

Comment: Done with the edit ;)

Comment: $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}$$ can be simply tackled through Euler's Beta function, since $\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}=(2n+1) B(n+1,n+1) = (2n+1)\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n\,dx$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0}(2n+1)z^n =\frac{1+z}{(1-z)^2}$.

Comment: Here is a list of more approaches (There was a question regarding this sum): [Evaluating:$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507838/evaluating-sum-n-0-infty-frac1-binom2nn) and [Calculate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548563/calculate-sum-limits-k-0-infty-frac12k-choose-k)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this series is convergent. Because we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)\cdot (2k-1)\cdot...\cdot k!}{(k!)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)\cdot (2k-1)\cdot...\cdot (k+1)}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{2k}{k}$$ which is obviously divergent.

Comment: The only series whose sum we can calculate are Geometric series and maybe telescopic ones?

Comment: @EEEB Definitely not. For example: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n!}=e$ is neither geometric, nor telescopic.

Comment: @projectilemotion is right, in general Taylor Series of certain functions can also be calculated. Except from that, I know that there are methods (like Integral Test) used for approximating the sum of more complicated series.