# Prove $\int_0^a (a^2 - x^2)^n dx = a^{2n+1}\cdot\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove 
$$\int_0^a (a^2 - x^2)^n dx = a^{2n+1}\cdot\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$  for $ n  \in N $ 
 My idea is to use binomial theorem and integrate partly, but I have not succeeded yet. Are there some hints?

Comment: Perhaps $a^2-x^2=(a-x)(a+x)$ and then manipulate to use Beta function...

Comment: A solution would depend heavily on what you know and do not know, hence some indications about that seem mandatory.

Comment: And let $x=au$?

Comment: $$\int_0^1(a^2-(au)^2)^n\mathrm dau$$ $$= a^{2n+1}\int_0^1(1-u^2)^n\mathrm du$$ $$= a^{2n+1}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n\dbinom nk(-u^2)^k\mathrm du$$ $$= a^{2n+1}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\dbinom nku^{2k}\mathrm du$$ $$= a^{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dbinom nk$$

Comment: Looks like I'm late here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hint:  consider the case where $a = 1$.

Second hint:  Let $$I_n = \int_{x=0}^1 (1 - x^2)^n \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 (1-x^2)^{n-1} - x^2 (1-x^2)^{n-1} \, dx = I_{n-1} - \int_{x=0}^1 x (x(1-x^2)^{n-1}) \, dx,$$ then with this last integral, perform integration by parts with the choice $$u = x, \quad du = dx, \quad dv = x(1-x^2)^{n-1} \, dx, \quad v = -\frac{1}{2n}(1-x^2)^n.$$  This yields a recursion relation for $I_n$, which you can then solve.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* @Heropup's approach seems to be the most adequate. But you can also succeed by applying the binomial theorem.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^a\left(a^2-x^2\right)^n\,dx&=\int_0^a\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(-x^2\right)^k\left(a^2\right)^{n-k}\,dx\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^ka^{2n-2k}\int_0^ax^{2k}\,dx\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^ka^{2n-2k}\frac{1}{2k+1}a^{2k+1}\\
> &=a^{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

There is a nice identity called *Melzak's formula* which can be used to solve (1).

> **Melzak's formula:** Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$, i.e.
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k
> \end{align*}
>   Let $y$ be an arbitrary complex number. Melzak's formula states that for $y \ne 0,-1,-2,\ldots,-n$
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x+y)&=y\binom{y+n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{f(x-k)}{y+k}\tag{2}\\
> \end{align*}

The whole chapter 7 in H.W.Goulds *[Combinatorial Identities for Stirling Numbers](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/)* is devoted to this formula. An easily accessible proof can be found in *[New proofs of Melzak's identity](http://128.84.21.199/pdf/1603.07006.pdf)* by U. Abel, H.W. Gould and J. Quaintance.

> Setting $f(x)=1$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain from (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{1}{\binom{\frac{1}{2}+n}{n}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{\frac{1}{2}+n}{n}&=\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-(n-1)\right)}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{\left(2n+1\right)\left(2n-1\right)\cdots\left(3\right)}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{2^nn!}\\
> &=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}
> \end{align*}
>   the claim follows.

Comment: (+1). This sum was also evaluated at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503530/), I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Take out $a$ as a common factor, giving $\frac{1}{a^{2n+1}} \, \int_0^1 (1 - y^2)^n dy = a^{2n+1} \int_0^1 (1 - y^2)^n dy$ then use the integral over $y$ is standard (or easily determined) and given as $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$.