# How do you expand this function into a Maclaurin series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The function is given with:

$$
f(x) = \dfrac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2}}}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a website where users just solve homework exercises. In order to get your questions well received, it is better to write something else, such as your attempt or the approach you have given to solve your exercise.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549028/deriving-maclaurin-series-for-frac-arcsin-x-sqrt1-x2?noredirect=1)