# Finite summation including binomial coefficients and double factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I came across the following summation:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}\dbinom{n}{k}\,\,\,\,(n\in\mathbb{N}).
$$
$\tbinom{n}{k}$ are binomial coefficients, $n!/k!(n-k)!$.

Mathematica told me that the answer is $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ at least for $n\le20$, but I couldn't prove it.

Does anyone have an idea to prove, for any $n$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\,\,\,\,?
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Since $\ds{\pars{2k}!! = 2^{k}\pars{k!} = 2^{k}\,\Gamma\pars{k + 1}}$ and $\ds{\pars{2k +1}!! = {\pars{2k + 2}! \over 2^{k + 1}\pars{k + 1}!} =
> 2^{-k - 1}\,\,{\Gamma\pars{2k + 3} \over \Gamma\pars{k + 2}}}$, we'll have:
>   $$
> {\pars{2k}!! \over \pars{2k + 1}!!} =
> 2^{2k + 1}\,\,\,{\Gamma\pars{k + 1}\Gamma\pars{k + 2} \over \Gamma\pars{2k + 3}} =
> 2^{2k + 1}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k}\pars{1 - t}^{k + 1}\,\dd t
> $$

---

and
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,
{\pars{2k}!! \over \pars{2k + 1}!!}\,{n \choose k}} =
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\bracks{-4t\pars{1 - t}}^{\, k}\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}\bracks{1 - 4t\pars{1 - t}}^{\, n}\,\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - 4t\pars{1 - t}}^{\, n}\,\,\dd t =
\color{#f00}{1 \over 2n + 1}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{1 - 4t\pars{1 - t} = 4\pars{t - \half}^{2}}$.

Answer (score 3):

A way to prove it is using the binomial inversion:

> **Theorem**: If $$a_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}b_{k}
>  $$ then $$b_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}a_{k}.$$

Now since holds $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\frac{\left(2n\right)!!}{\left(2n+1\right)!!}$$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/proving-a-binomial-sum-identity-sum-k-0n-binom-nk-frac-1k2k1)) your claim follows.
Another way is observing that $$\frac{\left(2k\right)!!}{\left(2k+1\right)!!}=\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{k}dt
 $$ hence $$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{\left(2k\right)!!}{\left(2k+1\right)!!}= & \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(1-t^{2}\right)^{k}dt \\
 = & \int_{0}^{1}t^{2n}dt \\ = & \color{red}{\frac{1}{2n+1}}.
\end{align}$$